# How to mark a file for _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, devops

I am trying to build a solution using TFS with MSBuild and in the build log I do not see all of the config files being copied from the Build directory to the bin. Only two out of five. They are all in the same directory. What could be preventing them from being copied?

I should point out that they are in the Getting list earlier in the build.  I'm reading that I need to set these config files as "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways"?  Currently I only see a couple being copied under that heading.    How would I set them as such?

Comment: What is the build action for the files that aren't being copied? Look at the MSBuild file, or in the properties explorer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the build action for the files in the MSBuild file isn't "None". You can update this either by directly modifying the MSBuild file, or by looking in the properties explorer in Visual Studio.